# How to write unit tests for zzz.R file in R package

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I am currently developing an R package and used a `zzz.R` file to set an option value when the package is loaded and also to return a load message. The content of my `zzz.R` file is as follows:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) { 
  op <- options()
  op.mypackage <- list( 
    mypackage.small_neg_threshold = -1e-6
  )

  toset <- !(names(op.mypackage) %in% names(op))
  if (any(toset)) options(op.mypackage[toset])
}

.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) { 
  packageStartupMessage(
    "

  Hello World!!!

" 
  )
}
```

I wondering how one could write a test case in such that entire `zzz.R` file would be captured as being covered (after running something like `devtools::test_coverage()`